# My Ubuntu server crashes and I don't know what causes the crash

Tags: server-crashes

My server gives the error below. Let me know if more details needed.

```
Modules linked in: xt_nat veth nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo br_netfilter bridge stp llc overlay ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG nf_log_syslog xt_comment nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_compat nft_counter nf_tables binfmt_misc nfnetlink nls_iso8859_1 ipmi_ssif intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common sb_edac x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp kvm_intel kvm rapl intel_cstate input_leds hpilo ioatdma dca acpi_ipmi ipmi_si acpi_tad acpi_power_meter mac_hid dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc sch_fq_codel scsi_dh_alua coretemp ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic usbhid
```

and also it gives me this

```
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#16 stuck for 127s! [migration/16:113]
```

more info :

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

```
Linux asiadb 5.15.0-83-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 14 09:30:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZCXj.jpg)

[image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQaZU.jpg)

[image-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA0EZ.jpg)

[image-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdiPJ.jpg)

Comment: can you execute below and share: cat /etc/*-release uname -a free -h df -h as current info provided isnt enough to diagnose, above commands will tell people more about your environment so they know what u have. also, what apps you using when you experience this. does this happen randomly? how long server been up when you experience this. Regards, Kaleem

Comment: Yes, a LOT more information would be useful. For starters, what do you mean by "crash"?   You should get "soft lockup" notifications every 10 seconds when somethings stuck in a loop. Do they always lead up to a "crash" event? Do the stack traces always point to zap_pmd_range? Are you running any memory profiling software on this host?

Comment: Please read this Q/A, and (start to ) do a memtest  [watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for ...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264859/watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu6-stuck-for-23s)